# CoreBluetooth Scan

Tags: nstimer, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I want to achieve results is to use a timer cycle once every 8 seconds a Bluetooth scanner, the peripheral signals in the presence of dictionary in startScan method to Rssi printed, beginning effects are normal, but after the beginning of the cycle times a problem, sometimes scanning devices, or less than the number of peripheral wrong, I would like to ask what can increase the stability of it?

```
-(void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber*)RSSI{
  NSString *str = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",peripheral.identifier];
  localName = [advertisementData objectForKey:@"kCBAdvDataLocalName"];
  NSArray * numberArray = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"> "];
  NSString * numberStr = [numberArray objectAtIndex:1];
  **[mutableDictionary setValue:RSSI forKey:numberStr]; //Save rssi**
}

-(void)startScan:(NSTimer*)timer{
  [_manager stopScan];
  database = [self openDB];
  resultSet = [database executeQuery:@"select * from AboutDog "];
  while([resultSet next]){
      sqlite= [[Sqlite alloc]init];
      sqlite.rssiString =[mutableDictionary valueForKey:numberStr];
  }
  [database close];
  [self.collectionView reloadData];
  [_manager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil options:options];
  mutableDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new]; //Each side of the empty
  [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:8 target:self selector:@selector(startScan:)userInfo:nil repeats:NO];//Cycles every 8 seconds
}
```

Comment: Rather than polling every 8 seconds you might find it more reliable just to scan and handle the devices as they appear.  I think the problem you have is that a given peripheral may not advertise during the time you are scanning.  You can specify `CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey` in the options to get continuous scanning but this will drain the battery.  The other approach you can take is to age devices out of the dictionary - only removing them after they haven't been seen for 3 or 4 scans

Comment: Mou, you don't want to do what you do. Listen to Paul and do as he says. :)